# Modular Visitor Pattern

Tags: c++, template, inheritance, qt, visitor-pattern

## Motivation

I created this because the Visitor pattern felt like the most appropriate, but I also wanted to satisfy the Open/Closed principle with respect to the logic when visiting specific node types.  I also needed the ability to "return" a specialized value type from visitation without wanting to tie that knowledge to the visitable hierarchy.  Why should those objects have to care what I'm making out of them?

The Visitor/Visitable classes are defined mostly as by Alexandrescu.

[Note: The existing codebase uses Qt, so I left the Qt classes intact rather than switch them for std equivalents.]

## Visitor/Visitable Classes:

```
// Strawman base class
class BaseVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseVisitor() {};
};

// Class template for visitor, template params are type visited and return type of visit
template <class T, class R>
class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual R visit(const T &) = 0;
};

// Class template for visitable, template param is the return type of accept

template <class R>
class BaseVisitable
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseVisitable() {};
    virtual R accept(BaseVisitor &)
    {
        return (R) 0;
    }

    typedef R ReturnType;
protected:
    template <class T>
    static ReturnType acceptVisitor(const T &visited, BaseVisitor &visitor)
    {
        if (typeid(visited) == typeid(T))
        {
            auto p = dynamic_cast<Visitor<T, ReturnType> *> (&visitor);
            // We want to ignore non-specified nodes
            if (p != nullptr)
                return p->visit(visited);
            else
                return (ReturnType) 0;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("typeid(T) doesn't match typeid(visited)! Did your inherited class miss DEFINE_VISITABLE()?");
        }
    }

};

#define DEFINE_VISITABLE() \
            virtual ReturnType accept(BaseVisitor &v) const \
                { return acceptVisitor(*this, v); }
```

## Visitable Hierarchy

```
class VisitableBase : public BaseVisitable<void>
{
public:
    DEFINE_VISITABLE();
};

class VisitableDerived : public VisitableBase
{
public:
    DEFINE_VISITABLE();
};

class VisitableDerived2 : public VisitableBase
{
public:
    DEFINE_VISITABLE();
};
```

## Code Under Review

This is where I did things differently than implement the standard Visitor class.  I basically added subclasses of `Visitor<T,R>` and moved some logic from the master Visitor (that inherits all the `Visitor<T,R>` classes) into a base class.

### Base Builder Class

Simple class to collect the values I'm trying to return from visitation. Doesn't have to be a class template, just contain the appropriate logic to aggregate the returned values.

```
class Collector
{
protected:
    void addToStack(const std::string& s)
    {
        m_stack.push(s);
    }

    QStack<std::string> getStack()
    {
        return m_stack;
    }

private:
    QStack<std::string> m_stack;
};
```

### Converter

Inherits from `Visitor<T,void>` and virtually from `Collector`.  This let me decouple conversion from visitation, and retain common logic for aggregating the results since the traditional `Visitor` classes can't access their derived master Visitor to do so.

```
template <typename VisitedType>
class Converter
    : public Visitor<VisitedType, void>
    , public virtual Collector
{
public:
    Converter(){ }
    virtual QString convert(const VisitedType& visited) = 0;

    virtual void visit(const VisitedType& visited) override
    {
        addToStack(convert(visited));
    }
};
```

### Example Converter Classes

These inherit from `Converter<T>` and are my modification points.

```
class VisitableDerivedConverter : public Converter<VisitableDerived>
{
public:
    virtual QString convert(const VisitableDerived&) override
    {
        return "Normally converted VisitableDerived";
    }
};

class FabulousVisitableDerivedConverter : public Converter<VisitableDerived>
{
public:
    virtual QString convert(const VisitableDerived&) override
    {
        return "Fabulously converted VisitableDerived";
    }
};

class VisitableDerived2Converter : public Converter<VisitableDerived2>
{
public:
    virtual QString convert(const VisitableDerived2&) override
    {
        return "Normally converted VisitableDerived2";
    }
};
```

### The client-facing Visitor

This is largely the same as the traditional visitor, but using variadic templates because not all nodes need to be handled.

```
template<typename... T>
class ConverterVisitor : public BaseVisitor
    , public T...
{
public:
    void talkAboutIt()
    {
        for (auto each : Collector::getStack())
        {
            qDebug() << each;
        }
    }
};
```

### Usage

Example usage:

```
{
    auto newBuilder1 = new ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter>();

    auto newBuilder2 = new ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>();

    auto newBuilder3 = new ConverterVisitor<FabulousVisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>();

    VisitableBase* visitable = new VisitableDerived();
    VisitableBase* visitable2 = new VisitableDerived2();

    qDebug() << "Builder1...";

    visitable->accept(*newBuilder1);
    visitable2->accept(*newBuilder1);

    newBuilder1->talkAboutIt();

    qDebug() << "Builder2...";

    visitable->accept(*newBuilder2);
    visitable2->accept(*newBuilder2);

    newBuilder2->talkAboutIt();

    qDebug() << "Builder3...";

    visitable->accept(*newBuilder3);
    visitable2->accept(*newBuilder3);

    newBuilder3->talkAboutIt();

}
```

And corresponding output:

```
 Builder1...
 "Normally converted VisitableDerived"
 Builder2...
 "Normally converted VisitableDerived"
 "Normally converted VisitableDerived2"
 Builder3...
 "Fabulously converted VisitableDerived"
 "Normally converted VisitableDerived2"
```

### My Thoughts

#### Pros:

- Feels clean
- Implementing new conversion logic for a given node is easy
- Construction and conversion logic are fairly well decoupled

#### Cons:

- `ConverterBuilder` and `Collector` are more strongly coupled than they first appear, and effectively need to be designed together (or at least `ConverterBuilder` must be designed with consideration of the `Collector`)
- Relies on the "dreaded diamond," which people don't like (but [multiple inheritance is not necessarily evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-not-evil))

#### Hopes and Dreams:

- I would really love a lot more `static_assert`s and compiler errors to make it harder to use incorrectly.  For example, including both `VisitableDerivedConverter` and `FabulousVisitableDerivedConverter` would ideally fail to compile, but currently results in that node getting skipped entirely (the `dynamic_cast` fails.)
- The pattern would be a lot more reusable if `Collector` logic was a policy of the `ConverterVisitor` and configurable at design time.  I can see a way to do this by having the `Converter` implementations also be class templates, but they shouldn't require knowledge that aggregation policies even exist.  It's also highly desirable that the `Converter` implementations remain unit-testable, and hence instantiable in isolation.

Comment: When I copy your code to a Qt-Creator console project I get two compiler error messages (will put them into the two next comments for better readability):

Comment: `C:\Users\g-mak_000\Documents\ModularVisitor\main.cpp:145: Fehler: there are no arguments to 'getStack' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'getStack' must be available [-fpermissive]
         for (auto each : getStack())
                                   ^`

Comment: `C:\Users\g-mak_000\Documents\ModularVisitor\main.cpp:50: Fehler: no matching function for call to 'std::exception::exception(const char [91])'
             throw std::exception("typeid(T) doesn't match typeid(visited)! Did your inherited class miss DEFINE_VISITABLE()?");
                                                                                                                              ^`

Comment: Fix these 1st please before asking for a review. For easy access I'll share what I have at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29d8770d48f4a6ba) (fails to compile and run of course there).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited to fix the second error, MSVC allows that constructor for std::exception, but it's non-standard.  Here's an edited version of your coliru that compiles and runs: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd7059231595baef

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't know what the other error is, but I don't get it in MSVC and -fpermissive lets it compile anyway.

Comment: -fpermissive is the devil and you should feel bad even thinking about using it. The fact that msvc compiles it is hardly a reason to assume it's correct C++. Please test with at least two compilers.

Comment: @rubenvb This is fixed now.   Collector can't be a class template because getStack doesn't depend on a template parameter and thus needs to be resolvable the first time through (from what I understand.)

Comment: 9 months later, I figured out how coliru works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d58f9de7f23e93d0

Answer (score 4):

#### The visitor pattern and open closed principle. There is a mild conflict here.

The visitor pattern is very good when you have a static class hierarchy and just want different ways to traverse the nodes in some collection. In these situations the visitor pattern behaves very well.

**BUT**

If the class hierarchy is not stable and you are adding new types of nodes then it does not behave very well. This is because every new class that you add to the hierarchy will require a new method in the visitor object  (unless you want to default them using some template method to handle the new nodes).

#### Design

Not sure I agree with your design at all.
This is what a standard visitor pattern looks like.

```
 class A;
 class B;
 class C;
 class D;
 class E;
 class AlphaVisitor
 {
      public:
          virtual void visit(A& a) = 0;
          virtual void visit(B& b) = 0;
          virtual void visit(C& c) = 0;
          virtual void visit(D& d) = 0;
          virtual void visit(E& e) = 0;
 };
 class A {public: accept(AlphaVisitor& v) {/* STUFF*/ v.visit(*this);}};
 class B {public: accept(AlphaVisitor& v) {/* STUFF*/ v.visit(*this);}};
 class D {public: accept(AlphaVisitor& v) {/* STUFF*/ v.visit(*this);}};
 class E {public: accept(AlphaVisitor& v) {/* STUFF*/ v.visit(*this);}};
```

In your code both `accept()` and `visit()` return an R. This is not normal. It may be very big object that is returned. You don't want to copy that around. It is more common for the `AlphaVisitor` to accumulate state as it visits objects. Then when it has finished visiting then you can access the state from the visitor object itself.

```
 A                a(/* construct some large graph of A/B/C/D/E */);


 MyDerivedVisitor visitor;
 a.accept(visitor);

 ResultType value = visitor.getResult();
```

#### Code Review

R had better be constructible with an integer. Otherwise this will fail to even compile.

```
virtual R accept(BaseVisitor &)
{
    return (R) 0;
}
```

Runtime type checking is not a good idea. That is why we have the visitor pattern to prevent this.

```
static ReturnType acceptVisitor(const T &visited, BaseVisitor &visitor)
{
    if (typeid(visited) == typeid(T))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("typeid(T) doesn't match typeid(visited)! Did your inherited class miss DEFINE_VISITABLE()?");
    }
}
```

Please don't do this:

```
auto newBuilder1 = new ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter>();

auto newBuilder2 = new ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>();

auto newBuilder3 = new ConverterVisitor<FabulousVisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>();
```

Just declare your variables locally.

```
ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter>   newBuilder1;
ConverterVisitor<VisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>  newBuilder2;

ConverterVisitor<FabulousVisitableDerivedConverter, VisitableDerived2Converter>   newBuilder3;
```

The same as above

```
VisitableDerived  visitable;
VisitableDerived2 visitable2;

visitable.accept(newBuilder1);
visitable2.accept(newBuilder1);
```

Comment: Woops, my mistake on those autos, wasn't thinking hard enough when I wrote the usage part.  The BaseVisitable and Visitor are Alexandrescu's Acyclic Visitor from Modern C++ Design almost verbatim, although I usually end up using void as the return type, so it's fair to question even bothering with it.  I added the typeid check and exception to catch when DEFINE_VISITABLE has been missed in the visited hierarchy, rather than let it silently upcast.

Comment: The visited hierarchy in my case is stable and large, so that's not a concern.  One question: is that the limit of your critique, or did you stop at the most egregious things?  It was the classes built on top of the Acyclic Visitor pattern that I was most hoping for feedback on.